# ldapsearch against Active Directory fails authentication + search params wrong

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am using `ldapsearch` from OpenLDAP tools to search our corporate Active Directory for my email and phone number.  This query is a test to ensure that I can authenticate against the domain so I can set up a linux wiki with NTLM authentication.  My theory is that if I can successfully query the AD for information, then I am a step closer to getting my wiki to authenticate against AD (I have [instructions to set up moin wiki under ActiveDirectory](http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuAD)).

The problem is that I can't seem to get the `ldapsearch` query right.  I have seen many tutorials on the net that indicate that `-D` should be something like `-D "Americas\John_Marshall"`; however, I keep getting `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)` error messages when I use `Americas\John_Marshall`.  The only time I get sensical results is when I query with the parameters below.  However, even then, I can't figure out how to get email and phone number.

```
[John_Marshall@WN7-BG3YSM1 ~]$ ldapsearch -x -h 10.1.1.1 \
 -b "cn=Users,dc=Americas" mail telephonenumber -D "cn=John_Marshall,dc=Americas"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=Users,dc=Americas> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: mail telephonenumber -D cn=John_Marshall,dc=Americas 
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
[John_Marshall@WN7-BG3YSM1 ~]$
```

Can someone give me pointers on what I'm doing wrong with the `ldapsearch` query above?  Our AD ldap server is 10.1.1.1 and the AD domain is "Americas".

### Steps to final solution (the actual answer is in Wolfgang's response):

Using information in the comments and Wolfgang's answer, I was able to cobble the solution together but it wasn't pretty getting there...

`ldp.exe` wasn't very useful to me; however, I started sniffing the servers that Outlook authenticated against and substituted that IP address in my queries.  Suddenly I was getting correct authentication, and ran a query using `ldapsearch -x -h <new_ip_addr> -D "Americas\John_Marshall" -W -b "dc=MyCompanyName,dc=com"`.  The results of this query (which was basically a raw data dump of much of our corporate LDAP directory) allowed me to refine the `-b` parameter (search base).

Comment: I've battled out AD auth for web apps a few times.. Sounds like you're having to dig in a bit more than I've had to in the past.. Something that I have found helpful for understanding the AD/LDAP environment I've been dealing with, is this little windows app called "ldp" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224543). You may be past the point of things like that being helpful, but just in case, there you go.

Comment: @Doc Yes, I use ldp for everything when digging into AD for the purpose of formulating queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are a few things that could be wrong with this:

1. You are specifying simple authentication, but you are not providing a password and you are not telling ldapsearch either to collect a password from the command line. Does the user John_Marshall not have a password? If he does have one, it has to be provided somehow. Either specify `-w <passsword>` or `-W` (to enter a password at a prompt).
2. Is the users binddn really `cn=John_Marshall,dc=Americas`? In our AD, just as an example, my own binddn would be "`dn: CN=Wolfgang Schulze-Zachau,CN=Users,DC=aminocom,DC=com`", i.e. there is no underscore between first name and surname
3. A binddn of "`cn=John_Marshall,dc=Americas`" is possible, but looks a bit short to me. Of course, this all depends on how your AD is configured. Can you verify that this really is the DN for that user? When you look at AD Users and Computers, what is the complete list of tree items leading to that user?
4. If you don't specify a filter, you'll get a list of all items that are in the searchbase. That could be a very long list.

### *OP Edit*:

The correct incantation that worked was:

```
[John_Marshall@WN7-BG3YSM1 ~]$ ldapsearch -x -h <new_ip_addr> \
-D "Americas\John_Marshall" -W \
-b "cn=John_Marshall,ou=users,ou=austin,dc=amer,dc=MyComanyName,dc=com" \
mail telephonenumber ""
```